# Integrating matlab C++ shared library in C++ code

Tags: c++, matlab, shared-libraries, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to call a simple MyAdd function compiled by matlab compiler into C++, but I fail to initialize matlab runtime. Here is my code

```
#include "MyAdd.h"
void main(){
    mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0);
}
```

I correctly set the linker and include directories. In fact this code compiles without any problem, when I run my code, in debug or release I get the following error:

```
    'MyPro.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Mina\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CCSharedLibTest\Debug\MyPro.exe', Symbols loaded.
    'MyPro.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'
    'MyPro.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'
    'MyPro.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'
    The program '[13016] MyPro.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
```

I guess I have issue with 32bit/64bit. Any suggestion to solve this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to call mclTerminateApplication before returning from main.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that my matlab is 64bit, while I was compiling in Win32 mode. I had to uninstall my matlab and install a 32bit version.